# moving files around different sub domains

Tags: php, subdomain, directory

I am currently working on a quite a big project for a client and one of the things that they want is to be able to create new isntances of their software on different sub domains and each using its own database, they want to be able to do this in the most automated way possible. A quick overview of the way a new isntace created is:

1. A new sub domain is created by one of their administrators by going into thier 123-reg control panel
2. A new database is created by one of their administrators by going into their 123-reg control panel
3. They login to an centeral admin panel and fill in a form which then copies over a zip file of the software to the new sub domain and unzips it.
4. The script then edits the database connection class with the database infromation supplied in the form.
5. The script then checks the connection and creates the tables
6. Finally the admin database is updated with the instances new information.

The problem I am having is moving files around different sub domains. For instance the admin panel is at `admin.website.com` and as an example a new instance might be located at `instance.website.com` no matter what I try I cannot get a file to move to a different sub domain... Does anyone have a solutions to this? For anyone wondering the directory structure is like so:

- /public_html/admin/
- /public_html/instance/
- /public_html/instance_2/

etc.

Comment: are the domains hosted on the same box?

Comment: Yes they are all on the same server. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the appropriate access, could you use the [PHP FTP library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) to move the files over FTP?

That would mean that it didn't matter if in future instances were on different servers.

Comment: I did have a quick look into the FTP library but after about an hour or two of trail and error I gave up, I continually get warning saying `No file in directory` No matter what path I supply with the fput / fget fucntions, also there doesn't seem to be a function to copy a file from one directory to another. Thanks

Comment: looks to me as though ftp_put ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php ) should do exactly what you suggest, but I haven't used it. I don't know whether a machine could FTP to itself either, I guess, but you should be able to check that from the command line. If you can figure out how to make the transfer from command line FTP on your server that should show you what parameters you need to use in PHP.

Comment: I currently have no access to the command line (I think) I have never used 123-reg before and I don't have access to their control panel as all that is left upto my client. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$source = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . "/whatever/";

$target = str_replace('instance', 'instance_2', 
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . "/whatever/";
```

But both have to exist on the same server

Answer (score 0):

I'd use scp if you have SSH enabled on both machines. For instance, you can run the following command on your target machine:

```
scp username@domain1.com:/public_html/ /public_html
```

Source: http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php

Answer (score 0):

Glenatron's idea is probably going to be the only way you can go here since (I'm assuming here) you don't have SSH permissions. But, you might be in luck if the ISP let's you modify the skeleton directory structure that is installed when you create the subdomain in the panel. You might be able to point it to the production codebase and create a simple PHP script that allows you to modify the DB settings without having to edit code. You could also run your DB initialization queries there. I know you wanted it to set those automagically, but I'm just providing tip of the tongue possibilities.

Good luck!